# Can't paste into input more than once

Tags: jquery

The script should allow users to paste a video ID into the input box but are unable to do so after one paste/no paste at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#get-thumbnail").click(function() {
     $('#thumbnail').html("<a href='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + $('#video-id').val() + "/maxresdefault.jpg'><img src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + $('#video-id').val() + "/maxresdefault.jpg'><a/>");
   });
});
```

Is there something I could add to the JS to allow for pasting multiple times?

Comment: Where is the code what you use for pasting? Do you have some more code where we can have a look at?

Comment: There is no code for pasting, it's just buggy when pasting via menu or hotkeys - I don't know if the JS could've done that.

Comment: There's nothing there that has any effect on the input box.

Comment: `I don't know if the JS could've done that.` > Nope

Comment: Ok thank you - I'll explore other causes.

Comment: `.append`, `.prepend`, `.appendTo` instead of `.html` which overwrites code.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). This way the content of `#thumbnail` won't be replaced.

```
$('#thumbnail').append("<a href='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + $('#video-id').val() + "/maxresdefault.jpg'><img src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + $('#video-id').val() + "/maxresdefault.jpg'><a/>");
```